# Using Amplify, Stripe Checkout, and AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, stripe-payments, amazon-cognito

I have a client application that uses StripeJS + Stripe Checkout to create a session and then redirects to a success URL.

My `/webhook` call is conveniently called alerting the application to successful payment. To update a Cognito user with a `custom:paid` attribute, I'm attempting to pass the user's access token around through my Lamda route's authorizer and then into the Stripe object through either metadata or [client_reference_id](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-client_reference_id).

Stripe limits the character length of both of those fields which prevents using that approach exactly.

How can one pass Cognito user credentials through Stripe to correlate successful payments to the existing user scheme?

Comment: Stripe metadata can have values with a length of up to 500 characters. What are you storing that you require more? I guess you could split the data into several key/value pairings, but that maxes out at 40 keys * 500 characters = 20,000.

Comment: @PaulAsjes a Cognito (Amplify) access token is 965 characters which puts it over both client_reference_id and metadata limits. I'd tried both first. Splitting in metadata is a good idea.